# C# scrable game coding. Can't combine string and int?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
int[] punten = 
    { 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 4, 8, 8, 4 };

char[] alfabet = new char[27];

for (int i = 65; i < 65 + 26; i++)
{
    char letter = (char)i;
    alfabet[i - 65] = letter;
}

foreach (char letters in alfabet)
{
    lblAlfabet.Content += letters.ToString() + "=" + punten.ToString() + "\n";
}
```

Can't combine the string and int , they should line up next to eachother in a label.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. What problem are you having? Which line of code? What do you mean by "Can't combine string and int"?

Comment: When i start up my alfabet is nicely showing but my int[] punten is showing as system.int32

Comment: Well, `puten` is a whole list of numbers, which number do you want to put into the `Content`? `puten[2]` for example will pick the 2nd one. It sounds like you need to use a `for` loop again like you did above, so you can do `puten[i]`.

Comment: What is your expected result? Calling `ToString` on a integer array will display "System.Int32[]"...

Comment: I'm assuming your 65 is there because that it the integer value of the character 'A'.  A character in an integer expression (for example, `i < 'A' + 26` will be promoted to being an integer.  It makes for much more readable code.

Comment: Thank you all, it works :)!

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd be better of using a dictionary and explicitly assigning your points to each letter rather than iterating over ASCII characters and storing in separate arrays.

```
var letterPoints = new Dictionary<char, int>()
{
    {'A', 1}, {'B', 2}, {'C', 3}, {'D', 1}, {'E', 1}, {'F', 4}, {'G', 2}, {'H', 2}, {'I', 1}, {'J', 4},
    {'K', 4}, {'L', 2}, {'M', 3}, {'N', 1}, {'O', 1}, {'P', 3}, {'Q', 10}, {'R', 1}, {'S', 1}, {'T', 1},
    {'U', 4}, {'V', 2}, {'W', 4}, {'X', 8}, {'Y', 8}, {'Z', 4}
};

foreach (var lp in letterPoints)
{
    lblAlfabet.Content += $"{lp.Key}={lp.Value}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `punten` are in alphabetical order and the array has the correct number of elements you could try

```
int i = 0;

foreach (char letters in alfabet)
{
    lblAlfabet.Content += letters.ToString() + "=" + punten[i++].ToString() + "\n";

}
```

Also, as per @CharlesMay's comment below, alphabet should only have 26 elements, i.e.

```
char[] alfabet = new char[26];
```

Comment: also, I think alfabet[] should only be dimensioned to 26 or an Out of bounds condition will occur.

Comment: @CharlesMay - I wondered that too and I'm sure you are correct.

Comment: Don't forget Scrabble has 2 blank tiles (wildcard) - may be the 27th value is needed to represent that (it would of course need correctly initialising)

Comment: Thank you all, it works :)! And indeed, it should be 26. Ty